# How to use serif as mathfont only while I use kerkis, math?

Tags: beamer, fonts

Simply, I'll just show pictures to explain this problem. I compiled following codes:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

...
```

then,
[image]

This is not `serif`. It is some kind of `kerkis`+`serif`. So, I want to use `kerkis, kmath` as textfonts only while I use `serif` as mathfonts:

[image]

Do you know some methods?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Judging by your first screenshot, I'd say that the math font is indeed a serif font -- it's simply not **Computer Modern** Math, which is what the second screenshot seems to show. (You simply commented out the directive `\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}` to generate the second screenshot, right?) Please confirm that what you really want is to employ Computer Modern math fonts.

Comment: the second screenshot is the modified screenshot.

Comment: I want some methods to represent the second screenshot as compiling result.

Comment: "I want..." When my kids were little, my one-and-only reply to any statement of theirs that began with 'I want' was, " 'I want' lives in the trashcan." They are teenagers by now, and they've successfully mastered lots of aspects of what it means to be polite and to avoid coming across as rude. In generaly, one tends to get a lot more done by not being needlessly confrontational.

Comment: Sorry.. I'm not good at English.. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{kerkis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

normal text

\[
    F = ma
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]